# How to prevent a WPF context menu from appearing on the empty space of a tree view?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a simple context menu on a dynamically populated tree view.

How can I prevent this context menu from appearing if I right click on empty space (below the last item) ? I tried to use the ContextMenuOpening event, but it is [buggy](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/353112/contextmenu-opening-event-doesnt-fire-properly) and isn't raised.

---

```
            <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Open" Click="MenuItemOpen_Click" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeView.ContextMenu>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    <!-- Select node on right click : -->                        
                    <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you define the context menu of the items instead ?

You could through a style define a TreeViewItem context menu by binding it to a static resource that eventually has x:Shared set to true. It will be defined in one place once and for all. Unless you have a very specific reason to make it happen at the treeview level, this way effectively does what you want : no menu on empty space.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="menu" x:Shared="true">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open" Click="MenuItemOpen_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource menu}"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView">
            <TreeViewItem Header="item1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="item2">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="item3">
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Tell us more about what you're trying to achieve otherwise.

**EDIT**

Notice that style has no x:Key therefore it applies by default to all TreeViewItems, if this isn't convenient for you as you might have different trees and items, you can explicitly assign the style at the TreeView level (ItemContainerStyle)

However, you see that it doesn't propagate to childrens :

[image]

But if you add a setter for the ItemContainerStyle property in that style, you can see that it gets propagated to childrens as well. (self-reference)

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="382"
        Height="159">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="menu" x:Shared="true">
            <MenuItem Click="MenuItemOpen_Click" Header="_Open" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource menu}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle1}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle1}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="item1" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="item2" IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="item3" IsExpanded="True" />
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Last but not least, you can define ItemContainerStyleSelector should you need red, blue or greens items according their content and still retain that inheritance from the style.

Comment: I didn't know I could do that, that's why I didn't do it :) So yes, that's what I want to achieve, this works, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but maybe you can test it view HitTestResult in combination with your MouseEventArgs e

```
DependencyObject k = null;
var hitTest = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(tv_treeview, e.GetPosition(tv_treeview));
        if(hitTest != null)
        {
            k = hitTest.VisualHit;
        }
```